# Is it inefficient to repetitively evaluate expression in loop condition?

Tags: c++

As a beginner, I frequently see loop conditions which contain function calls and some computation intensive expressions, like below (e.g from C++ primer, loop statement):

```
for(int *beg = begin(array); beg != end(array); ++beg) ;
```

My concern is: 
Since the condition is checked in each iteration, isn't it costly to evaluate the expression inside condition (here it runs the `end()` function) ?

Comment: How are we supposed to know why the author of your book (the book we don't know, BTW) chose the code sample that they did? Contact that author. You've posted one line of code, totally out of any context, with none of the explanatory text that the book surely includes, and asked us to explain the author's thought process. It's hardly likely that we can do so, unless by some miraculous series of coincidences the book author happens to frequent this site, happens to accidentally see this question, and happens to recognize his own code sample.

Comment: Books aren't necessarily perfect. They're often highly flawed. Regardless, this sort of micro-optimisation is almost always irrelevant (and could be performed by the compiler).

Comment: What book?
We're not the author.
This isn't a programming question.
It's an example of what you use something for.

Comment: It depends on the compiler. They might optimize this for you such that the end condition is evaluated exactly once.

Comment: @Cyber, good answer. light weight question for light weight answer.

Comment: @Mankarse, good answer and serves as a cross reference of the other answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, this may not actually have measurable performance impact: If the loop body takes several times longer (quite common for ordinary code), or the loop as a whole is not a bottleneck, any optimization of the loop condition is wasted.

Second, usual implementations of `end()` are perfect candidates for inlining. And once it's inlined, since `end()` must not have side effects, the iterator construction is subject to loop invariant code motion. After these two transformations, there is literally no difference to the "manually optimized" version, at zero extra effort for the programmer.

Third, even if the second point did not apply, for most code it's a small price for more concise code, *especially* for beginners. The same reasons that make the optimizations describe above trivial also make it trivial for humans to apply the same transformation, **should the need arise**.

Comment: _"the maximum loss of efficiency for the whole loop is inversely proportional to the cost of the loop body"_ Say what?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: apparently he's referring to the execution time contribution of the `end` call, that its contribution relative to the loop as a whole, is ... inversely proportional to the cost of the loop body, when that loop body cost is assumed to very much greater.

Comment: Well that's certainly true but I don't see how it's a useful or informative metric.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Cheers nailed it, I need to find a better way to word. Point being, if the loop body takes longer than `end()` (and for a lot of interesting code, it does) then the `end()` call is the wrong place to think of optimizing.

Comment: @delnan: Well that's certainly true also but it's still just an argument against needless micro-optimisation; it's not the same as saying that it actually _wouldn't_ be an optimisation. I think the OP was looking for confirmation that it could optimise, not that one should bother. Your second paragraph covers the rest of it very well I think.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right that the argument is quite generic, but it's nevertheless important here and in any other context. I included it because the phrasing of the question hints at a quite naive approach to performance reasoning. Amdahl's law (of which this is the sequential case) is obvious in hindsight but needs to be pointed out to everyone once.

Answer (score 0):

Because books are didactic, readability is more important than performance.  It's easier for beginners to grasp the principle of algorithms if one doesn't have to figure out the optimization tricks !

In real life too this makes sense : end condition tend to be complex and influenced by each iteration.  So it's much safer and more maintenable to make end conditions understandable, and hide implementation details.

If performance really matters, first think about B.Kernighan's statement:  *"don't diddle code to make it faster, but find better algorithms"*.

For very simple time critical loops, it could be worth looking at facts. The way you write your loop matters.  Here some benchmarks on huge iterations searching in strings:

- traditional iterator approach checking for .end() each time:  14 seconds
- caching .end() at begin of loop in a variable :  10 seconds, 30% better !
- using counter&index, checking against .size() each time: 860 ms
- starting counting from the end backwards to 0 :  670 ms, 22% better !
- using a pointers to c_str(), reduced the whole thing to ...  63 ms !

But keep in mind that the best opptimizer is your compiler.  With optimization turned on,  the timings are 1274 ms, 677 ms, 42 ms, 42 ms and 33ms, i.e. from 50% to 92% better !!